# Beats audio not working in linux mint on HP envy

Tags: linux-mint, audio

I just installed Linux Mint 18 on my HP envy 15 and i was trying to get a nice sound using hda-jack-retask.
I followed this instructions 
https://incognitech.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/beats-audio-hp-envy-15-on-ubuntu/
as i did for my previous distros.
But when i try to apply the changes i get this error:

tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/reconfig: No such device

After that the mute led turns on and the laptop goes mute even trying to change volume (pressing the mute/unmute button seems to change the audio level on the OS but in any case the led keeps being turned on).
Only after a reboot the built-in device return available (in the sound settings) and after selecting it the sound comes back.

Does anyone know how to help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems in the past when trying to retask jack outputs. [I wrote this small post entry to remind me how I did it](http://yalneb.blogspot.com.es/2015/08/71-surround-sound-on-linux.html).

Also, make sure your device is not muted in `alsamixer`. You will see two red letters M (MM) signifying it is muted. In that case press 'm' on your keyboard to unmute the selected device.

Comment: I used hdajackretask but i get that error!

Comment: @MGabrielli You probably did, but just in case: did you run `hdajackretask` with `sudo`?